After exported, date not showing in displayed format using kendo pdf export in angular
Issue
I'm using kendo pdf export in angular and trying to export the long webpage with accordions which expands the accordions and exports the whole page, which is as expected. The only issue is date is showing in different format than that on the webpage.
Webpage (Expected)

Exported PDF

Expectations and What I tried already?
I want all dates in PDF to be as shown on webpage, which works fine with kendo date input (Stackblitz). Unfortunately, I've not implemented kendo date component for all dates through the project instead used regular date input and at this stage it is difficult to redo entirely with kendo date input. I don't see any kendo API for PDF export which takes care of date format as well.
Anyone encountered same issue? Is there any other way to achieve this using some other package which takes care of date format as well as expanding accordions and exporting to PDF? Thanks in advance.
